# Xcode Storyboard Zoom Magnification

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, storyboard, zooming

I'm currently using the storyboard feature to position views. Due to the nature of these views, they need to be positioned with precision.

I'd like to view the Storyboard Scene/View in a magnification/zoom level greater than 100%, but it doesn't seem to be possible using the standard zoom in/out feature.

Is it possible to do this?

Note - I understand how to use the 'Size Inspector'.

Comment: You might want to accept one of our answers. There is no way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I am almost positive it is not possible to do this. You are stuck with 100% zoom. However, if you need great precision, you could try selecting the element you wish to move and use the arrow-keys to move the item around accurately.

However, like MacN00b, I do not use Storyboards a lot, so perhaps there is some top-super-secret setting buried somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't look like there is a way to do this, but there is at least one alternative that works fairly well:

1. Go to System Preferences > Accessibility > Zoom
2. Turn on the keyboard shortcut or scroll gesture

You should now be able to zoom in on any part of the operating system, including storyboards.

To make editing even easier, enable these options, some of which are found under More Options...:

- Turn off Smooth images
- Change Zoom Style to Picture-in-picture
- Window Position: Follow mouse cursor
- Cursor style: Crosshair
- Enable temporary zoom

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the reasons I don't use storyboard but prefer good old fashion individual xibs. I don't think it is possible to zoom in past 100%, you may try double clicking on the background, I know that normally zooms in.

Comment: Double clicking on a `background` will just zoom in to the 100% if you had less before. Otherwise nothing happens.